# How to add live chat widget to wordpress admin area using functions.php

Tags: wordpress

I'm wanting to add a live chat widget, such as Facebook Messenger, to the backend of a WordPress site. I want it to only show up on pages in the wp-admin area.

I tried using this in functions.php but it was throwing errors because of the HTML I'm guessing. Any ideas on how to get this to work?

```
function enqueue_live_chat() {

    <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v9.0'
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
  <div class="fb-customerchat"
    attribution=setup_tool
    page_id="######"


 theme_color="#9482ff">
      </div>
    
    }

add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_live_chat' );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `add_action( 'admin_footer', 'callback function' );`

so it will help you add code to the admin backend, read more about action [Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_footer/)

```
<?php
function enqueue_live_chat() { ?>

    <!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        xfbml            : true,
        version          : 'v9.0'
      });
    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

  <!-- Your Chat Plugin code -->
  <div class="fb-customerchat"
    attribution=setup_tool
    page_id="######"


 theme_color="#9482ff">
      </div>
    
<?php    }

add_action( 'admin_footer', 'enqueue_live_chat' ); ?>
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. For anyone else trying to do this, make sure to add a closing PHP tag before the HTML/JS snippet and then add an opening PHP tag after the snippet.

Comment: @Jeremy update the code with ending and closing with PHP tags, thanks for inputs